# Streaming Parsers (JSON/XML) for AS3/Flex/Adobe AIR application

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, json, parsing, air

Are there any stream-reading, parsing libraries available for json or xml formats in AS3?  I'm setting up a long-polling application, using URLStream/URLRequest.  I do not have control over the data I'm receiving other than a choice between formats.  I'd like to have a parser that can handle fragments at a time, which would allow me to trigger custom events when certain complete fragments become available.  Thoughts?  What are current AIR applications doing to handle this?

Sample API:

```
var decoder:StreamingJSONDecoder = new StreamingJSONDecoder();
decoder.attachEvent("onobjectavailable", read_object); 

while (urlStream.bytesAvailable) 
{
  decoder.readBytes(get_bytes(urlStream)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup.

Have a look at the AS3 Corelib: http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/

It's an Adobe library. There should be more info on [labs.adobe.com](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/ActionScript_3:resources:apis:libraries).

I did have an issues with the RSS parser on the date format, but other than that, everything seemed fine.

Goodluck!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think the APIs provided by as3corelib support streaming.  I added some sample code to my original question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry...I didn't read the question properly. The latest details on the as3 JSON library I read were here:http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2008/12/as3-json-library-now-a-little-less-strict.cfm. Can't help much though :(

Answer (score 1):

The current AIR release (v2.5) bundles a newer WebKit that has native JSON support, via JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse().

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use a [URLStream](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLStream.html) instance to progressively download the data from a remote network, then decode the JSON result when enough data is available.

Something like this (not tested, just to give you an idea):

```
var stream:URLStream = new URLStream();
stream.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, handleProgress );
stream.load( new URLRequest( "/path/to/data" ) );

function handleProgress( event:ProgressEvent ):void
{
    // Attempt to read as much from the stream as we can at this point in time
    while ( stream.bytesAvailable )
    {
        // Look for a JSONParseError if the JSON is not complete or not
        // encoded correctly.
        // Look for an EOFError is we can't read a UTF string completely
        // from the stream.
        try
        {
            var result:* = JSON.decode( stream.readUTF() );
            // If we're here, we were able to read at least one decoded JSON object
            // while handling this progress event
        }
        catch ( e:Error )
        {
            // Can't read, abort the while loop and try again next time we
            // get download progress.
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```